# Exclude SpringApplicationRunListener when run test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I used a lib have a class implement SpringApplicationRunListener

```
public class FromLibApplicationRunListener implements SpringApplicationRunListener {...}
```

This lib load a lot of things I don't want to have while I run test. So I try to create a TestApplication

```
@SpringBooApplication
@ComponentScan(excudeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filters(type= ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, 
   value={RealApp.java, FromLibApplicatioRunListener})
public class TestApp {
   public static main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class ,args);
   }
}
```

But when I run TestApp, it still throw exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.....FromLibApplicationRunListner]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:435)
    ... 6 more
```

How can I remove this lib when I run test?

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiles for that:

1. Exclude a test profile for the listener class

```java
@Profile("!test")
public class FromLibApplicationRunListener implements SpringApplicationRunListener {...}
```

2. Set a profile for a test class

```java
...
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTest {
```

or set the application active profile in the `application.yaml` file (or `application.properties`)

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

Comment: I can't add code to FromLibApplicationRunListener because of it from external lib

Comment: In this case you can override the `FromLibApplicationRunListener` bean in a test configuration.

Comment: As I read code from Spring, It will use class loader, load all Class extends from SpringApplicationRunListener. If I create a class extend from `FromLibApplicationRunListener`, then it will load both of them

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution is in overriding a bean in a test configuration:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyTest.TestConfig.class)
class MyTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public FromLibApplicationRunListener listenerStub() {
            return new FromLibApplicationRunListener() {
                // override here used SpringApplicationRunListener methods
            };
        }
    }
...
}
```

or

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyTest.TestConfig.class)
class MyTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public SpringApplicationRunListener fromLibApplicationRunListener() {
            return new SpringApplicationRunListener() {};
        }
    }
...
}
```